# Rails: How to make private posts to be public after downgrading user's level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am new to RoR and in this app, I want to make the private posts public once the users cancel their paid service. In other words, the user's private posts will become public after the user downgrades the account level to standard.

Below is how I approach this scenario:

SubscriptionsController:

```
def downgrade
    subscription = current_user.subscription

    if subscription.delete
      downgrade_user_to_standard
      current_user_downgrade_posts
      flash[:success] = "Sorry to see you go."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Can't downgrade at this moment."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

ApplicationController:

```
protected

def downgrade_user_to_standard
     current_user.update_attributes(role: "standard")
   end

   def current_user_downgrade_posts
    privateposts = current_user.posts.where(private: true)
    privateposts.each do |privatepost|
      privatepost.posts_update_attributes(private: false)
    end
   end
```

When I tested it on server and console, I found that the private post created earlier was not made public as expected after downgrading a premium user to the standard level. 
Since there was no error message when I ran rails server, can anyone point out to me what steps I missed and how I can make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code should be in the controller but well...

you should change:

```
privatepost.posts_update_attributes(private: false)
```

with:

```
privatepost.update_attribute(:private, false)
```

if you don't care about validations, callbacks and touch timestamps then you can remove the loop and use:

```
current_user.posts.where(private: true).update_all(private: false)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did think about putting the code in model but it raised errors when I downgraded the user so that's why I put it in the controller.